# Angular Keycloak provider from node_module

Tags: angular, keycloak

I'm trying to push my keycloak provider into a npm module that can be reused in a suite of apps, all works fine when the module is in the base app but breaks with a bottled error when called from the node_module

code for interceptor:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, from } from 'rxjs';
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private keycloakService: KeycloakService) {}


  getToken() {
    return from(this.keycloakService.getToken());
  }


  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
    return this.addAuthorizationHeader(req, next)
  }

  addAuthorizationHeader(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.getToken().pipe(
      switchMap(token => {
        request = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: 'bearer ' + token
          }
        });
        return next.handle(request);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

code for the provider:

```
export function initializer(config) {
  const keycloak = new KeycloakService();     

  return (): Promise<any> => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        await keycloak.init({
          config,
          initOptions,
          bearerExcludedUrls: []
        });

        resolve();
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  };
}

export const KeycloakProvider: FactoryProvider = {
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: initializer,
  multi: true,
  deps: [KeycloakService]
};
```

app.module for AuthModule

```
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { KeycloakAngularModule, KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';
import { AuthInterceptor } from './auth-interceptor';
import { initializer } from './auth-provider';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    KeycloakAngularModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class AuthModule {
  static forRoot(config): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: AuthModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
          useFactory: initializer(config),
          multi: true,
          deps: [KeycloakService]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

app.module for main app
    ...
    import { AuthModule } from 'common-utils/dist/common-auth';

```
...
  imports: [
    AuthModule.forRoot({
      configOptions: ...,
      initOptions: {
        onLoad: 'login-required',
        checkLoginIframe: false
      }
    }),
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    KeycloakAngularModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  },
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

as mentioned this setup works just fine if the provider is in the app folder but not when coming from a node_module. Not sure what the issue is since the error is bottled in the module and doesn't occur in the apps version

error message:

Error: Uncaught (in promise): An error happened during access validation. Details:TypeError: Cannot read property 'resourceAccess' of undefined

Comment: Can you show the folder structure and import statements?

Comment: hi ya updated the code to reflect the current state, the folder structure is the default projects > module > lib setup that the angular cli uses. same for the main app just src > app. pretty new to angular so I try to keep things as by the book as I can.